# In wordpress auto publish post to facebook page i didn't get authorize in facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I m using WP2social auto publish wordpress plugin for sharing post from wordpress to facebook page. I created app also in https://developers.facebook.com.

Now i need to get authorize with facebook but i face the issue. Seems like there is an issue in App Domains or Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Please help me if you used any plugin or else for to share post from wordpress to facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Via Jetpack

1. Go to **Jetpack** → **Settings** → Sharing in your site’s WP Admin.
2. Click the toggle to activate Automatically share your posts to
   social networks.

FAuto Poster
Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/accesspress-facebook-auto-post/

**FAuto Poster** is a FREE WordPress plugin for auto post to your facebook account. You can use this to publish your site’s posts,pages and custom post types to your facebook profile and fan pages as soon as you hit the publish button in your site.

NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster
Link: [enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/)

This plugin automatically publishes posts from your blog to your Social Media accounts such as Facebook, Twitter, Google+(Google Plus), Blogger, Tumblr, Flickr, LinkedIn, ok.ru, LiveJournal, DreamWidth, Flipboard, Instagram, Telegram, Line, Diigo, Instapaper, Pinterest, Plurk, VK.com (VKontakte), YouTube, Scoop.

Comment: I tried above 2 plugin SNAP and FAuto Poster but i get same error   "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."    when i click on AUTHORIZE Button.